# Multichannel sampling with aliasing

Tags: sampling, nyquist, aliasing

if i have 2 sensors, sensor1 and sensor2, that sample a signal on complementary points so that sensor2 samples always between sensor1s sampling points. can I achieve the doubled sampling rate with the combination of both ?
so with merging both samples, although they are aliased individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; what you describe doesn't mathematically look any different than a single sampler at twice the rate. But they sensors need to sense the same, band-limited thing!

Actually, that's how some very high-speed ADCs work.

If you're not actually doing GS/s, getting a faster ADC would probably be easier than staggering multiple ADCs.

Comment: could you pls make a little bit more clear what you mean with band-limited thing? If my signal is bandlimited with a low-pass-filter to 4khz nyquist, and I sample the signal with two sensors with sampling rate 2khz but complementary sample points, i can merge them right? and what is GS/s?

Comment: another question, if i have a rotating machine, where i measure vibration on two axis with accelerometer sensor. I measure a phase lag in x , y axis. Do you think, combining the signals from different axis is comparable to a merge like i have decribed in my question? so merging two axis with phase lag, (if measured with aliasing) could increase the resolution, if the sampling points are known

Comment: *If my signal is bandlimited with a low-pass-filter to 4khz nyquist, and I sample the signal with two sensors with sampling rate 2khz but complementary sample points, i can merge them right?* no, if your Nyquist rate is 4 kHz, you need 8 kS/s sampling rate in total. But two 4 kS/s sensors would work. GS/s = gigasamples per second.

Comment: *I measure a phase lag in x , y axis. Do you think, combining the signals from different axis is comparable to a merge like i have decribed in my question?* No, that doesn't work. that's what I meant with "the same thing": these two sensors are observing different things.

Comment: ok, I understand, that the two sensors measure a different thing, but if the underlying rotation is constant, it can be considered the "same" signal and therefore lead to a higher resolution right? But I understand what you mean by that, I need the same signal to be sampled simultaneously. in the same axis

Comment: it's really not even closely the same thing; these axes are orthogonal, and hence measure independent parts of your acceleration.

Comment: i tested it with a neuronal network, and it reconstructed a higher resolution with the joint of the samples. I cant explain why the resolution increased. I understand what you mean,but even though they measure independent parts, they are related to the same underlying rotation, if that doesn't change, there should be a relation, but i dont understand it then :D

Comment: if these two orthogonal channels are linked, then through the mechanics of the system you're observing; that's not generally the case. That's one of the fundamental principles by which modern radio communications work, actually: signals can be projected onto two orthogonal oscillations, and the result is two completely independent signals, which can each be used and modified without modifying the other.